# Retrieve the name of the pointed-to function from a function pointer template argument at compile time

Tags: c++, c++20

I've got a situation like this:

```
template <class T, T (*fn) (T)>
struct Foo
{
    static consteval std::string_view printFnName()
    {
        return someMagicFunctionToRetrieveTheNameOfThePointedToFunction (fn);
    }
}
```

Where used like this

```
int bar (int) {}

std::cout << Foo<int, bar>::printFnName() << std::endl;
std::cout << Foo<float, std::abs>::printFnName() << std::endl;
```

I'd like to retrieve an output like this

```
bar
std::abs
```

Or alternatively like this

```
int bar (int)
float std::abs (float)
```

In theory the pointed to function should be known to the compiler at compile time. However, I'm not sure if there is any way to retrieve that knowledge – maybe this is something in the scope of some future reflection additions?
I'm open to solutions that use compiler specific extensions, as long as there are solutions for gcc, clang and MSVC. I'm alternatively also open for making `printFnName` a run time evaluated function if there is a better solution working for macOS, Linux and Windows. I'm using C++ 20

Comment: C++ does not have the kind of reflection that you are asking for

Comment: What problem are you trying to address here?

Comment: Just like a regular pointer doesn't know if points to a single object or an array of objects, a function pointer doesn't know the name of the function it points to, just the address of where it's stored.  That's all the information a pointer can store.

Comment: @NeilButterworth I'm trying to generate better readable output for unit tests. They are currently executed at runtime only, the desire for a compile time based solution is based by the plan to execute some tests on completely constexpr functions at compile time using `static_assert`

Comment: @NathanOliver I'm aware of that in the context of runtime-based function pointers, but when the pointer is a compile-time constant template argument, the compiler will already know the function that it points to when the code is compiled. So I would not find it completely unrealistic if there would be a way to ask the compiler to share that information it has with me ;)

Comment: You may or may not be able to do something with  https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Names.html

Comment: With a macro it would be trivial, but not sure it applies for your needs: `#define printFnName(fun) #fun`

Comment: It was a lot slower than the duplicate hammer, but I added what I think is a more useful answer, especially for this phrasing of the question, to the duplicate.